# Identify voltage regulator with the markings "9B 2P"

Tags: voltage-regulator, identification

I have looked through all the marking sites and where they lead, but have not found a replacement yet. Does anyone have a clue how to identify the 3V regulator marked "9B 2P"?

I've measured the voltages on a good one:

```
Pin 1: 4.7V
Pin 2: GND
Pin 3: 3.28V
Pin 4: NC
Pin 5: 4.7V
```

[image]

Comment: It may help to include an image with surrounding components for context.

Answer (score 4):

The package is SOT-89-5.
I think it is [XC3209F331PR or XC3209F332PR](https://www.torexsemi.com/file/en/products/discontinued/-2016/53-XC6209_12.pdf) from TOREX.

Picture from [LCSC](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/TorexSemicon-XC6209F332PR/C424708):
[image]

And below a little explanation of how I determined these 2 part numbers.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for the lesson as well.